# Pressures in multiple hydraulic drive system circuits when driving common drive shaft

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, torque

Assume that there are two 'idealised' and identical hydraulic drive system circuits each consisting of a connected positive displacement pump and hydraulic motor where both motors (from each independent circuit) are connected to the same drive shaft. Thus, the motor RPMs are mechanically synchronized. Assume that there is no pressure relief valves in the hydraulic circuits and they therefore have no maximum pressure.

My question relates to the pressure in the two hydraulic circuits when the pumps have equal flow and thus equal motor RPM. Will the circuits always have equal pressure (i.e. supply half the output torque each) or is it possible that one circuit could reach an equilibrium where one supplies e.g. 2/3 torque and the other 1/3 torque (and hence run at different pressures)? Is there some natural feedback in a real system that would lead to a balance in torque output?